# Powershell Compare Datatables and Send Email

Tags: powershell, dataset, compare, html-email

I need to find discrepancies from tables in two different SQL databases. The two tables have the same headers and look like below. If the sales of a same site, same store and same register in one database source are different with the other, then insert rows that have differences into email body and send it.

[image: Tables]

Email body should look like this

[image]

I tried Compare-Object and write to csv file to see if it works but unfortunately it did not save the differences in the csv file.

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $table1 -DifferenceObject $table2 -Property $headers -PassThru | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty SideIndicator | Export-Csv "$OuputFile diff.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Would you please help?

Thank you.

Comment: "it did not save the differences in the csv file.", well, what _did_ it save? :)

Comment: Why not do the comparison in the database? That's usually way more efficient than sending all the rows for client-based processing.

Comment: @vonPryz it would be much simpler if I can compare in database. But these two tables come from couple database instances and on different servers. I am not allowed to perform join on different database as per policy.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen it's blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code works for me

```
> $csvXStore = import-csv -Path "$OuputFile XStore.csv" $csvXBR =
> import-csv -Path "$OuputFile XBR.csv"
> 
> 
> $diff = Compare-Object -Ref $csvXStore -Diff $csvXBR -Property Date,
> Store, Register, Sales, test -PassThru |
> #    Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '<=' | 
>        Select-Object -Property * -ExcludeProperty SideIndicator
```